# How to increment a variable inside of a list comprehension

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have a python function which increments the character by 1 ascii value if the index is odd and decreases the ascii value by 1 if index is even .I want to convert it to a function which do the same increment and decrement but in the next set i want to increment by 2 and then decrement by -2 then by 3 and -3 and so on..

What Iam trying to do is to increment the counter variable by 1 each time an even index occurs after performing the ascii decrement.

I also dont want to do it with a `for` loop is there any way to do it in the list comprehension itself?

In my function if the input is

> input :'abcd' output: is 'badc' what i want is 'baeb'
>
> input :'cgpf' output: is 'dfqe' what i want is 'dfrd'

```
def changer(s):
    b=list(s)
    count=1
    d=[chr(ord(b[i])+count) if i%2==0  else chr(ord(b[i])-count) for i in range(0,len(b))]
    return ''.join(d)
```

I need something like `count++` as show but sadly python dont support it.

```
def changer(s):
    b=list(s)
    count=1
    d=[chr(ord(b[i])+count) if i%2==0  else chr(ord(b[i])-count++) for i in range(0,len(b))]
    return ''.join(d)
```

[Here is the runnable code](https://gist.github.com/incrypt0/f64fbce458f63105d7e2d30553217745)

Comment: I don't understand the part about the incrementing by 2, then 3, and so on... can you explain that part again please ?

Comment: Can you provide some sample input, sample output please ?

Comment: Okay i will edit the question to clear that doubt

Comment: @Nizar He wants `[b[0] + 1, b[1] -1, b[2] + 2, b[3] - 2, ...]`

Comment: No need, @Barmar made it clear :)

Comment: There's probably something in `itertools` you can use to create the sequence `1, -1, 2, -2, 3, -3, ...`. You can zip that with `b` and then add them.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If I correctly understood what you're after, something like this (compact form) should do:

```
def changer(s):
    return "".join(chr(ord(c) + ((i // 2) + 1) * (-1 if i % 2 else 1))
                   for i, c in enumerate(s))
```

We get index and character from string by means of `enumerate()` and use that to feed a generator comprehension (as asked for) far of index (`i`) and character (`c`) from the string.

For each ASCII value of `c`, we add result of integer division of `i` (incremented by one as index was `0` based) by `2`  and multiply it by `(-1 if i % 2 else 1)` which flips `+/-` based on even/odd number: multiply by `-1` when modulo of `i` division by 2 is non-zero (and `bool()` evaluates as `True`), otherwise use `1`.

Needless to say: such comprehension is not necessarily easy to read, so if you'd use it in your script, it would deserve a good comment for future reference. ;)

Answer (score 2):

Combine a stream of plus/minus with the string.

```
import itertools
s = 'abcdefg'

x = range(1,len(s)+1)
y = range(-1,-len(s)+1,-1)
z = itertools.chain.from_iterable(zip(x,y))
r = (n + ord(c) for (n,c) in zip(z,s))
''.join(chr(n) for n in r)
```

---

I don't think I'd try to put it all in one line. Uses generator expressions instead of list comprehensions.

Answer (score 1):

Try the code below,

```
def changer(s):
    return ''.join([chr(ord(j) + (i // 2 + 1)) if i % 2 == 0 else chr(ord(j) - (i // 2 + 1)) for i, j in enumerate(s)])

s = 'abcd'
changer(s)
```

output

```
baeb
```

Comment: if you can you please explain it a bit more the code iam having trouble understanding it

Comment: @incrypt0 `[i//2+1 if i%2==0 else -((i//2)+1) for i in range(5)]` wil give `[1,-1,2,-2,3,-3,4,-4]`

Comment: what enumerate function does is it returns the index along with value of iterator, using this `(i // 2 + 1)` we will get the sequence 1,-1,2,-2,3,-3.

Comment: I hope this is something you need.